# Warning ao usar ibase_fetch_object()

Tags: php, postgresql

Tenho uma aplicação `PHP` que sincroniza dados de um banco para outro, em um dado momento, quando consultando um banco de dados `Postgre`, após preencher devidamente as variáveis `$db` e `$sql`  tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
$query = ibase_query($db, $sql);
while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($query)) {
...
}
```

O problema acontece na linha 2, no `ibase_fetch_object($query)`, o log diz:

> Warning: ibase_fetch_object(): operating system directive WriteFile
>   failed There is not enough space on the disk.

Não encontrei nada a respeito de WriteFile nesse método na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-fetch-object.php).
Alguém pode me dizer o porquê desse erro e como resolvê-lo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema e foi da maneira mais óbvia possível, **resolvendo a falta de espaço em disco**.

Para contextualizar, o servidor onde a aplicação em questão roda ainda tinha 20GB de espaço livre, então quando apresentei o erro e disse que o problema era a falta de espaço fui refutado. 
Não cheguei a descobrir se é por padrão ou é configurável, contudo acredito na segunda opção, mas no Linux, quando a percentagem de armazenamento livre chega a 5%, somente o usuário ROOT e mais alguns previamente autorizados podem escrever em arquivos. Nesse caso, a aplicação conseguia criar seus arquivos de LOG, mas não conseguia escrever neles. Essa situação se estendeu até o que o próprio PHP não conseguisse escrever em seus arquivos de sessão, então minha teoria foi aceita e resolvemos o problema com limpeza de disco e aumento de armazenamento.